# Get text from textbox that inside asp:FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Hello i just need to get text from texbox,but my textbox is inside of asp:FormView and i get to it.All textbox's that out side i can use and take value but not all textbox that in side asp:FormView.It says element doesn't not exits in content

What i am missing here?

My html.

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server">

   <input   id="txt_Out"   runat="server" tabindex="1" value="trst">

  <asp:FormView ID="MainFormTemplate" runat="server">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <li class="li_result" runat="server">
      <input id="txt_In"   runat="server" tabindex="1" value="test">
       </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:FormView>
    </<asp:Content>


    Server

 public void btn_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    string text=txt_Out.Value;//Good
    string text1=txt_In//error Dont exist
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is inside FormView so you can not access it directly.you need to find it inside FormView Control.

Do

```
(Textbox)MainFormTemplate.FindControl("txt_In");
```